# Dynamic query in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I am trying to call a function in a dynamic query with parameters of types `varchar` and `datetime`.

My query looks like this:

```
declare @Query nvarchar(max)
declare @date datetime

set @date ='02/02/2015'
set @Query = 'select xxx, dbo.myfunction(yyy,'+date +',sa) '

exec @Query
```

When I execute this query, I am getting error:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: Add your `myfunction` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with dynamic query, as you define variable (`@Query`) to execute query, its data-type is `nvarchar` or `varchar`.

So while passing the parameter you must convert any value into `nvarchar` or `varchar` type.

so simply do this. Always give space while concatenate string.

```
set @Query = 'select xxx, dbo.myfunction(yyy,' + cast( date as nvarchar(50)) + ',sa) '
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this invariant date format, also you are passing `date` not `@date`:

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @date DATETIME

SET @date = '20150202'
SET @Query = 'select xxx, dbo.myfunction(yyy,''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), @date, 112) + ''',sa) '

PRINT @Query
```

But you can directly declare @date as varchar and you also need to add quotes around `yyy` and `sa`:

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(8) = '20150202'

SET @Query = 'select xxx, dbo.myfunction(''yyy'',''' + @date + ''',''sa'') '

PRINT @Query
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
set @Query = 'select xxx, dbo.myfunction(yyy,'''+date +''',sa) '
```

That way, the date is quoted. Also, `@date` would probably be better declared as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @Query nvarchar(max)
declare @date datetime

set @date ='02/02/2015'
set @Query = 'select xxx, dbo.myfunction(''yyy'','''+CAST(@date as nvarchar) +''',''sa'')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

You may CAST @date to datetime in your function.

Comment: same error alj
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: Hi Datha , i have edited the answer. if it is still showing the same error ,please provide what you have written inside the function and let us know what you r trying to achieve .